# Stripe SDK integration using swift and flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, stripe-payments, applepay

I am trying to integrate Apple Pay in iOS using flutter. I am using method channels to communicate with swift and get the payment process completed. I have followed the documentation which is in this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom#apple-pay)

However, I believe I have stuck in the very ending part which I don't understand how to continue the flow. Since I am using flutter UIs, I don't need iOS ViewControllers.

This is the code that I have tried so far in the `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func handleApplePayButtonTapped(result: FlutterResult){
    let merchantIdentifier = "my.apple.merchant.id"
    let paymentRequest = Stripe.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier:merchantIdentifier, country:"US", currency:"USD")
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
    PKPaymentSummaryItem(label:"Fancy Hat", amount:50.00),
    PKPaymentSummaryItem(label:"iHats, Inc", amount:50.00),
    ]

    if Stripe.canSubmitPaymentRequest(paymentRequest){
        //next steps ???
        result(String("Can submit payment request"))
    }else{
        result(String("Can't submit payment request"))
    }
}
```

I am calling this code in flutter UI using this code:

```
Future<void> _doPayment() async {
String returnMsg;
try {
  final bool result = await platform.invokeMethod('checkIfDeviceSupportsApplePay');
  if(result){
    final String status = await platform.invokeMethod('handleApplePayButtonTapped');
    print(status);
  }
  returnMsg = '$result';
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  returnMsg = "Failed: '${e.message}'.";
}
print(returnMsg);}
```

I already have a Stripe publishable key as well as a Heroku deployed backend. If you checked my swift code, you will see where I am stuck at the moment.

As I have understood the flow, what is remaining to be done is

- send the card details to the backend and get a token
- using the token, send the payment details to the Stripe server

I am very new to swift language and code samples will be greatly helpful for me to continue with.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're following the Stripe Custom iOS Integration, using the native PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.

You should read through the integration steps here: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom#apple-pay

Basically, your next steps would be

- instantiate a PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController with the paymentRequest
- Set yourself to its delegate
- present the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController
- implement the relevant delegate methods to get back an Apple Pay token (PKToken)
- convert PKToken to STPToken (a Stripe token)

All these steps and more are detailed in the link above.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. Would you be able to provide a sample implementation for the submitTokenToBackend() method? that would be greatly helpful.

Comment: @SajadJaward that entirely depends on how your client<>server communication works. But basically you would post your token ID over to your server-side endpoint. Your server-side endpoint would parse the token and create a Charge on Stripe. And then return a response to your client's request, for your app to display on the client-side